# matlab remove NaN from matrix

Tags: matlab, vectorization, nan, cell-array

I have a matrix:

```
raw = 

'alon'     'tomer'    'ilana'    'T1'     '2'      '53'      '24'       'NaN'
'ilana'    'oren'     '6'        'a'      'g'      'g'       'gsh'      'NaN'
'dikla'    'aba'      'mama'     'a'      'h'      'ghfs'    'bfsbf'    'NaN'
'4'        'NaN'      'NaN'      'nn'    'NaN'    'NaN'     'hadhd'    'NaN'
```

**and I want to remove NaN and to get:**

```
    'alon'     'tomer'    'ilana'    'T1'     '2'      '53'      '24'
    'ilana'    'oren'     '6'        'a'      'g'      'g'       'gsh'
    'dikla'    'aba'      'mama'     'a'      'h'      'ghfs'    'bfsbf'
    '4'         ''        ''         'nn'     ''       ''        'hadhd'
```

how do I do that?

I tried a lot of suggestions, but I got errors:

1)

```
>> raw=raw(~isnan(raw(:,2)),:)
??? Undefined function or method 'isnan' for input arguments of type 'cell'.
```

2)

```
raw(isnan(raw(:,1)),:) = [];
??? Undefined function or method 'isnan' for input arguments of type 'cell'.
```

3)

```
raw(~any(isnan(raw),2),:)
??? Undefined function or method 'isnan' for input arguments of type 'cell'.
```

4)

```
T(cellfun(@isnan,T))={0}
??? Error using ==> cellfun
Non-scalar in Uniform output, at index 1, output 1.
Set 'UniformOutput' to false.
```

I tried Ansari's solution, but now I got:

```
raw = 

'alon'     'tomer'    'ilana'    'T1'    '2'    '53'      '24'       [0]
'ilana'    'oren'     '6'        'a'     'g'    'g'       'gsh'      [0]
'dikla'    'aba'      'mama'     'a'     'h'    'ghfs'    'bfsbf'    [0]
'4'        [    0]    [    0]    'nn'    [0]    [   0]    'hadhd'    [0]
```

it's not good for me, because I want to do:

```
size(raw,2)
```

and to get:

7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
f = @(x) strcmp(x, 'NaN');
nans = cellfun(f, raw);
raw(nans) = {''}; %cell(sum(nans(:)), 1);
```

`isnan` only works on matrices, so it won't work on cell arrays. Also your NaNs seem to be strings, not real NaNs.

At this point, all the 'NaN's will be empty strings. The following will remove entire rows or columns of empty strings:

```
raw = raw(:, arrayfun(@(i) length([raw{:, i}]), 1:size(raw, 2)) > 0); % for columns
raw = raw(arrayfun(@(i) length([raw{i, :}]), 1:size(raw, 1)) > 0, :); % for rows
```

For the last step though you might as well loop to keep the code clean and understandable (and easier to debug!). You're basically collapsing each row or each column by concatenating the strings, then checking if the length is zero, and if it is you're removing that row or column.

Comment: thank you, I understand, but I have a problem with this :/ I update my topic.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand - what problem do you have? I don't see any edits made to the question ...

Comment: So you also want to remove an entire row or column if it is all NaNs? (or all empty strings, after the substitution)

Comment: yes, I want to remove an entire row of column if it is all NaNs.. thank you again..

Answer (score 1):

An alternative answer using `regexprep`:

% the example data:

```
raw = { 'alon' 'tomer' 'ilana' 'T1' '2' '53' '24' 'NaN'; 'ilana' 'oren' '6' 'a' 'g' 'g' 'gsh' 'NaN'; 'dikla' 'aba' 'mama' 'a' 'h' 'ghfs' 'bfsbf' 'NaN'; '4' 'NaN' 'NaN' 'nn' 'NaN' 'NaN' 'hadhd' 'NaN' }
```

Here's the code:

```
output = cellfun(@(x) regexprep(x, 'NaN', ''), raw, 'UniformOutput', false);
NaNraw = cellfun(@(x) strcmp(x, 'NaN'), raw);
output(:,all(NaNraw,1)) = [];
```

So, first all `'NaN'` strings of `raw` are replaced with `''` by using `cellfun` and `repexprep`, the result is stored in `output`. Then a logical matrix `NaNraw` is created by comparing each string of `raw` with `'NaN'` by using `cellfun` and `strcmp`. Finally, the columns of `output` whose corresponding `NaNraw` columns contain only ones are removed.

```
output = 
'alon'     'tomer'    'ilana'    'T1'    '2'    '53'      '24'   
'ilana'    'oren'     '6'        'a'     'g'    'g'       'gsh'  
'dikla'    'aba'      'mama'     'a'     'h'    'ghfs'    'bfsbf'
'4'        ''         ''         'nn'    ''     ''        'hadhd'
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be overworking this.

```
cooked = regexprep(raw,'NaN','');
```

does it.

---

And of course, assuming you are not getting paid an extra $1000 for each line of code you don't write:

```
cooked = raw;
for I = 1:length(raw(:))
    if strcmp(raw{I},'NaN')
        cooked{I} = '';
    end
end
```

Comment: You're right about `regexprep`, a cell array of strings (`raw` in this case), is a valid input so in that case `cellfun` is completely unnecessary. About the `for` loop, I find it more convenient and less bug-prone to modify strings with regular expressions (`regexprep` in MATLAB). Using a `if strcmp` code structure instead of a nice and clean `regexprep` seems too complicated to me, with `regexprep` I can see the replacement in one single line of code.

Comment: @nrz The ability to write single lines that automagically do multi-index for loops is a nice thing in matlab.  But since the goal is usability at a low cost, it is important to remember that the for-loop which can be written without having to learn a bunch of new features is sometimes superior to the nth abstraction of single line matrix-array-cell-structure-object code that may take days to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
%# replace all 'NaN' with ''
raw(ismember(raw,'NaN')) = {''};

%# remove rows/columns of all empty strings
raw(:,all(cellfun(@isempty,raw),1)) = [];
raw(all(cellfun(@isempty,raw),2),:) = [];
```